# Python: When printing the contents of a class, I can't understand the order they're being printed in

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, printing, struct

I'm using python 3.3 and am experimenting with getting a good python equivalent of a struct in C. This is what I've settled on:

```
class employeeStruct():
    def __init__(self,name,title,number,salary):
        self.name   = name
        self.title  = title
        self.number = number
        self.salary = salary

boss = employeeStruct("Michael Scott", "Regional Manager", 3, 50000.00)

print(vars(boss))
```

The output of this is:

```
{'name': 'Michael Scott', 'salary': 50000.0, 'number': 3, 'title': 'Regional Manager'}
```

I don't understand the order the variables are being printed in. I tried using the [python tutor visualizer](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=class+employeeStruct%28%29%3a%0A++++def+__init__%28self,name,title,number,salary%29%3a%0A++++++++self.name+++=+name%0A++++++++self.title++=+title%0A++++++++self.number+=+number%0A++++++++self.salary+=+salary%0A%0Aboss+=+employeeStruct%28%22Michael+Scott%22,+%22Regional+Manager%22,+3,+50000.00%29%0A%0Aprint%28vars%28boss%29%29%0A&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=3&curInstr=9) but that didn't reveal anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is no meaning to the order; it's an artifact of the dict implementation.  If you want 'em sorted, use the [pprint](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`collections.namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections#collections.namedtuple) factory function subclasses `tuple` to add [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/operator#operator.itemgetter) properties. In 2.7/3.1, a `__dict__` property was added that returns a [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import namedtuple

Employee = namedtuple("Employee", 
                      "name title number salary")

boss = Employee("Michael Scott", "Regional Manager", 3, 50000.00)
print(repr(boss))
print(vars(boss))
```

Output:

```
Employee(name='Michael Scott', title='Regional Manager', number=3, salary=50000.0)
OrderedDict([('name', 'Michael Scott'), ('title', 'Regional Manager'), ('number', 3), ('salary', 50000.0)])
```

Comment: Thanks! That doesn't quite explain why dict seems to output in such an unpredictable order, but that's exactly what I needed.